# How to get the URL from browser in ASP.Net MVC 5 Application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, url, asp.net-mvc-5

I have ASP.Net web application, and I want to fetch the URL present in the browser. Below is my attempt

```
public static string UrlForGoogleAuth
{
    get
    {
        UrlHelper url = new UrlHelper(HttpContext.Current.Request.RequestContext);

        string host = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Host;
        if (host == "localhost")
        {
            host = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Authority;
        }
        string result = "https://" + host + url.Action("LoginSettingsSubmit", "Security");
        return result;
    }
}
```

**Scenario 1.** Url: https://sample.com - works fine and `host variable` fetches `sample.com`

**Scenario 2.** Url: https://sample.com:2345 - `host variable` just fetches `sample.com` instead of `sample.com:2345`

Work Around (temp fix: hard code 2345 in the result)

```
 string result = "https://" + host + ":2345" + url.Action("LoginSettingsSubmit", "Security");
```

But I am looking for a fool proof solution with no hard-coding. Also, If I can achieve the result without changing alot of stuff in already written code, then that would be great.

```
EDIT:

    public static string UrlForGoogleAuth
    {
        get
        {
            UrlHelper url = new UrlHelper(HttpContext.Current.Request.RequestContext);   
                host = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Authority;
            string result = "https://" + host + url.Action("LoginSettingsSubmit", "Security");
            return result;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why are you only setting `host` to `Url.Authority` for `localhost`? Why not use `Url.Authority` all the time? And in __Scenario 1__ I'd be surprised if the `Host` for https://sample.com was abc.com.

Comment: I am just a beginner. Pardon my ignorance. I will try to do what you have told and will let you know if I get what I want.

Comment: abc was a typo. thanks. fixed it.

Comment: @Unbreakable Are you trying to construct URL based on Action Method Name and Controller Name?

Comment: Actually it's a redirect for google authentication. My action name and controller name are not dynamic. if that is what you mean. Actually, I need to append action and controller name to the URL so that when the google authenticates the login, I need to hit a `HTTPOST` method again which takes in the code returned by the google authentication service.

Comment: @DanWilson: You are right. Url.Authority worked for me. One doubt. If the url does not have any port then Url.authority won't create any issue right? Still my code will work right?

Comment: I mean if no port is there then I will be able to get result as "h ttps://sample.com" right?

Comment: I have added an EDIT section as per your suggestion.

Comment: @Unbreakable correct, I have added an answer to address this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`Uri.Authority`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.authority(v=vs.110).aspx) will give you the host name and port (if the URL has one).

> Gets the Domain Name System (DNS) host name or IP address and the port
>   number for a server.

```
// www.sample.com:8080
Console.WriteLine(new Uri("https://www.sample.com:8080/controller/action").Authority);

// www.sample.com
Console.WriteLine(new Uri("https://www.sample.com/controller/action").Authority);
```

So in your case, you would just use the following:

```
HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Authority
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I will remember "ignorance is prohibited in SO" :) :D :D

Answer (score 3):

This will give you the complete URL:

```
var url = Request.RequestContext.HttpContext.Request.RawUrl;
```